# how to setup csrf cookie name and header from protractor to make post request to django server to setup fixture to test angular app?

Tags: django, angularjs, csrf, protractor

I need to make a post request to django server to insert fixture for my protractor test. To make post request to django, i need to change xsrf setting. i know how to do this in my app :

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}]);
```

I don't know how to access $httpProvider within protractor.

Comment: Can you provide more details. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

my_app_module is where i setup xsrf information. I simply include it in the array as below so that my_api_service can have the desired setup.

```
// in my test
it('something',function(){

    //insert fixture
    browser.executeAsyncScript(function(data,callback) {
        var api = angular.injector(['ng','my_api_module','my_app_module']).get('my_api_service');
        api.insert_new(data).then( function(data){ callback(data);} )
    },my_fixture)
    .then(function (output) { console.log(output); });

    //continue my test ...
```

})